# pcを買い換えた場合の.ssh設定

Tags: linux, ssh

今まで秘密鍵でLinuxサーバーにログインしていましたが、mac（PC）の買い替えをした場合は再度鍵ペアを作成する必要があるのでしょうか？

usb等で秘密鍵は新しいマシンに移動してあるのですがやはりログインできませんでした。

どなたかご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 「ログインできません」では状況が分からないので、具体的な症状やエラーメッセージを質問を編集して追記してください

Answer (score 2, accepted):

セキュリティ上、別PCの鍵ペアの共有はどうかは置いといて、
鍵ペアを再作成しなくても、秘密鍵を買い替えたmac(PC)に置けば、SSHはできるはずです

よくある繋がらない原因は

・パーミッションの問題
解決策は↓(mac側)
chmod 600 [秘密鍵のファイル名]

パーミッションを一度確認してみてください。

Comment: 有難う御座います。私の場合は`chmod 600 [秘密鍵のファイル名]`後に`Bad owner or permissions on /Users/[username]/.ssh/config`とエラー表示されていたのでその場合は`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`とやれば無事にログインできました。